# What is the best way put a program in windows startup?

Tags: scheduled-tasks, registry

There are many methods to make a program run at windows startup.

For example:

- Start Menu --> All Programs --> Startup
- Registry (HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Run)
- Task Scheduler
- More methods I don't know yet?

So the questions are:

- What is the differences between all those ways? (in the startup sequence/pipeline, technical, priority, system resources management, etc.)
- What is the best way to put a program in the windows startup?

Answer (score 0):

You can use the Startup Folder Trick:

```
C:\Documents and Settings\All Users\Start Menu\Programs\Startup
```

Or Win.ini Trick.

[Info](http://www.aumha.org/a/loads.php)

Edit: Sorry I went too fast.

The common way a program is executed at startup is via the Registry or via a Windows Services. I believe the Services' way might be executed before the ones in the registry (`..\CurrentVersion\Run`).

I dont think however the program have been executed changes how this program consume resources.

Comment: Better: `%ALLUSERSPROFILE%\Start Menu\Programs\Startup`